# GTMNSString+HTML uses object in struct

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

Probably pretty simple but i was just wondering I'm using GTMNSString+HTML.m / .h

[Found here](http://code.google.com/p/google-toolbox-for-mac/source/browse/trunk/Foundation/GTMNSString+HTML.m)

And I'm hitting a ARC snag. I'm unable to put Obj-C objects into struct's in ARC. Could someone help explain to me what the issue is putting an NSString inside a struct, and how I might fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Ok well dumb of me. Pretty easy to get around.

If you have this problem just head over to your Build Phases, and add `-fno-objc-arc` the line that the  GTMNSString+HTML.m is in this should let you build like a champ.